# What are the two-strand wires used for?

Tags: wiring, cables

Just got a new house. In the house, I saw many blank patch panels and when I open them, hiding behind them are these two-strand wires (AWG 22).

**Any idea what are these wires used for?**

I'd like to hard-wire the house with CAT6 cables.

[image]

Comment: Would guess phone cable.  Can you see/find where they go to.  That size would be used for low voltage, phone, door bell, or thermostat type stuff.  Low near floor usually phone jack placement.

Comment: Could also be wires for an alarm system. Look in closets and utility rooms for where they might all come together

Comment: As per answer from usersomenumber, that is blatantly central vacuum outlets. The giant hole with a pipe is a non-subtle clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is rough-in for central vacuum. Pipe and two wires for distant turn on vac. Some special outlets, central vacuum should be installed if you gonna use it. And hoses, connected to outlets, have switches.

Comment: Would there be vacuum piping an attached garage? Isn't the vac unit usually mounted on a garage wall?

Comment: @JimStewart I can not tell for every house but from I seen, yes. Most cases it is the place for central vacuum.

Comment: My house had similar.  And in the garage wall was a panel cover with vacuum markings molded in it.